Floating voltage line
I have installed a tracker into my excavator,
the tracker has power, oil pump and accessory wires.
The excavator has a negative isolation switch.
I have connected the power wires directly to the battery bypassing the isolation switch.
I have connected the accessory line to a voltage source that is +12v when the key is in position 1.
The issue is that when the isolation switch is disconnected this line becomes +12v in relation to the Acc input.
This means that the following is true.



Battery Isolator
Ignition
ACC Status




Off
Off
On


On
Off
Off


On
On
On



I believe the following accurately represents the internals of the excavator's ignition circuitry https://tinyurl.com/26hn8rrc
I need only the last statement to be true.
Battery Isolator: On | Key: On | ACC Status: On
I know I could just connect the negative power wire to the isolator and this would solve the issue, but I want the tracker to always be powered.
This question is about how to deal with a floating voltage line. I suspect needing something like an opamp or a not gate with some discrete components.

On further thought over the weekend, maybe I'm overthinking this. sensing the state of the isolation switch will do, so I could use a not gate and be done.
i.e. https://tinyurl.com/2ac4w5st

Mark - While I feel your pain (ie: your flag), if you want (or think) EE can better answer your question, frame it so there's nothing about a motor vehicle in it, otherwise they'll send it here. Give it a chance here, but I'm guessing you're overthinking the issue.
